# What are Strings... objects called as?

Tags: java, string

I didn't know what to look for so i couldn't google this one but..

What are `String...` parameters called as ?

And how do you get individual strings when more than one `String` object is passed through a `String...` object ?

Comment: looks like you are asking about var args?? show some code

Comment: They are called var-args.

Comment: And you can treat them as arrays/iterables in your code so accessing individual elements shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `String...` is syntactic sugar for an `String[]` and you access the values of the String array just like any other String array.  In fact you can write this simple method.

```
public static <T> T[] asArray(T... ts) {
    return ts;
}
```

This takes a vararg array can returns an array.

The key difference is that you can write

```
asArray(1, 2, 3); // much shorter.
```

instead of having to write

```
asArray(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a feature introduced with jdk 1.5. basically the last parameter of a method can be declared as  ... and that means

- from method caller pespective you can pass zero, one or many instances of that type
- within method the  .... param is basically seen as an array